# Removing overlapping areas between two rasters?

Tags: raster, grass-gis, raster-calculator, overlapping-features

I need some help with mapcalc.

I have two rasters:

- A contains cells with 1 or 2 or null;
- B has values>=1 or null.

I would like to delete areas where A overlaps with B, then get a resulting map where there is 1 where B has a value>=1 and null where both A and B have >= 1.

It seems easy but I'm trying many different combinations unsuccessfully.

Comment: What do you mean with *I would like to **delete** areas...*?

Comment: I mean that I would like to have null where both A and B have 1.

Comment: Do have both raster same extension and they are perfectly aligned?

Comment: Yes, both raster have same extension and they are perfectly aligned.

Answer (score 1):

It should be

```
g.region -p rast=A,B
r.mapcalc "C = if(A==1 && B==1, null(), if(B>=1, 1))"
```

Comment: It does just the opposite! Only the overlapping areas are conserved.

Comment: I solved it using one layer as a mask and mapcalc.